# Why it's 0 but not 255 here?

Tags: php

```
echo intval(chr(255));
```

I don't understand...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `chr()` function turns a byte into its ASCII equivalent and `intval()` function gets the integer value of a variable.

If we were to break the statement into two different lines, this would be:

```
$a = chr(255); // $a is now a string
echo intval($a);
```

If you check `intval()`'s documentation you will notice that:

> Strings will most likely return 0
>   although this depends on the leftmost
>   characters of the string. The common
>   rules of integer casting apply.

That's why the result is zero.

Answer (score 7):

The byte 0xFF does not represent a digit in either octal, decimal or hexadecimal what [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) is looking for. You probably wanted the [`ord` function](http://php.net/ord).

Answer (score 1):

To output 255, you need:

```
echo intval(ord(chr(255)));
```

There are 128 ordinal numbers in ASCII, the 255 comes out to be `ÿ` so when you convert it to a number with `intval`, it will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because `chr` delivers a string, in this case with just one character, the character 0xFF, or better known as `ÿ`.

`intval` on the other hand does a conversion from a string to an integer based on the content of the string, and not the characters.

```
  echo intval("33");        // will print 33
  echo intval("10", 8);     // will print 8
  echo intval("0xFF", 16);  // will print 255

  echo intval("m"); // will print zero...
                    //you can't convert letters like that to numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chr(255)
```

returns a character corresponding to ASCI 255

and `intval` try to bring out integer part from a variable

since chr(255) returns a non-numeric character so `intval` get no int value and return 0

Comment: There are just 128 characters in US-ASCII.